# Is there a metric for which the open unit interval is complete?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces, separable-spaces

Let, $I= (0,1)$ It is well known that $I$ is not a complete with respect to the Euclidean metric $(x,y)\mapsto |x-y|$.

However, $(I,|\cdot|)$ is separable.

> **Question:** Can we find a metric $d: I\times I \to(0,\infty)$ for which, $(I,d)$ is separable and complete?

Comment: Pull back the metric from $\mathbb{R}$ according to some homeomorphism between them.

Answer (score 3):

Try $J = (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ instead.  How about $d(x,y) = |\tan x - \tan y|$?

Answer (score 2):

Take a homeomorphism from the interval to $\Bbb R$ and pull back the usual Euclidean metric.